# Unable to resize thunderbird window

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, window

Thunderbird suddenly decided that it's window is no longer resizeable. I have been using 18.04 since it's release and never faced this issue with either thunderbird or any other application. Machine is up to date for software updates.

I don't get resize button (square button) on window. Resize menu only allows  veritcal resizing and not horizontal. Docking to top edge or left/right edges does not work either

Window is so huge horizontally, that I can not even see messages.

Starting thunderbird in safe mode also does not help. I have tried checking both the options available, individually and together.

Attempts to restart thunderbird or the PC have failed to improve anything.

Can I reset display settings of thunderbird without resetting all my other settings. I have lot of email accounts as well as RSS feeds.

No other desktop application is facing this problem, only thunderbird.

Comment: Did you try to start Thunderbird in "safe" mode?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, at the time of the post, I had not. Now I tried it and does not help. Editing post to add safe mode

Comment: Have you perhaps set window/app specific preferences? Try to find the window context menu (usually right click on the title bar) and go through the settings you find there.

Comment: @Murphy, I get minimize, resize as enabled items and maximize as disabled item. I even tried moving it different workspace. I can resize only vertically - that make it taller but can not do it same horizontally.

Comment: It seems to be related to my profile. If I rename original .thunderbird directory and start again, new window does not have any problem. Restoring back the original profile directory, same problems appear again. Anyone knows where thunderbird could be finding the window settings?

Comment: alt-right then unmaximise?

Comment: @pierrely, That option is disabled

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here (Ubuntu 18.04, Thunderbird 68.10.0). Maximise-option is disabled, horizontal adjustment too. Problem does not occur in newly created profiles. When switching back to original profile, problem is still there.

Found a quite effective work-around: In Thunderbird, try switching to the CardBook-Tab (Thunderbirds addressbook plugin) via Extras --> CardBook or Strg + Shift + B

Maximise-Button will reappear until next program start.

Answer (score 1):

[Your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211896/unable-to-resize-thunderbird-window/1278183#comment2035746_1211896) (search in profile directory) led me to this answer.

I had exactly the same problem since yesterday (26th September). Thunderbird window was suddenly a little bit too big on its right side. Couldn't reach maximize button which was off screen. Could move window thanks to sliding it, thus got back access to maximize button, but it has no effect. When clicking on "Resize" of system menu, can try to resize horizontally but it actually doesn't change. Resizing vertically worked normally.

Did you also install the **CardBook** extension? [flex's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278109/527764) indicated that this is a possible cause, and it is in my case too.

After many tries, I finally found that renaming the file `xulstore.json` fixed the issue.

Comment: where is the file you renamed? What did you renname it to?

Comment: No extensions are installed in thunderbird - except google calendar.

Comment: @Zanna, most probably LuckMorizur is mentioning is that file should not be there. Name does not matter as thunderbird is going to look by the name xulstore.json

Comment: The file is located in profile's thunderbird directory, which name is never the same, that's the reason why I didn't mention it — one can find it thanks to a search.

Comment: I confirm @flex 's answer (which means that renaming the file xulstore.json didn't fix the issue permanently): resizing CardBook extension has an effect on Thunderbird main window horizontal resizing ability.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the CardBook tab open works for me across restarts.

Comment: How does this answer address the question?

Comment: If you leave cardbook extension TAB open, you can resize thunderbird window again.